# Error "La instruccion insert exec no se puede anidar"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

estoy necesitado hacer un insert exec en una tabla temporal. Es decir, que se guarden en la temporal los valores que retorne el sp. Paso como lo estoy haciendo.

```
insert into #tmp_punitorio exec cobranzas 1,@idcliente
```

Lo que tambien probe fue agregando luego de #tmp los campos de esa tabla.

A continuacion adjunto el error que tira

> "La instrucción INSERT EXEC no se puede anidar. "

Comment: El error es claro, estás anidando `INSERT EXEC`. Significa que dentro de el procedimiento estás utilizando otro procedimiento para insertar en una tabla. Hay varias formas de solucionar el problema, pero no se puede hacer sin más detalles.

Comment: Claro es justamente lo que necesito hacer. Que detalles mas puedo pasar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Necesitarías incluir el código de los procedimientos involucrados (PA_AC_SELECT_DETALLE_COBRANZAS, los que son llamados desde este y el que llama a este). Aunque posiblemente sea demasiado problema para un sitio como este.